# How can I test /_ah/bounce?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have implemented a bounce handler by copying the code from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/bounce), but now I would like to test that this code works before I push it out to production.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using a Chrome extension called [POSTMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to formulate a POST request with all of the required parameters, as shown in the docstring of the BounceNotification class:

```
      post_vars: a dict-like object containing bounce information.
          This is typically the self.request.POST variable of a RequestHandler
          object. The following keys are expected in the dict:
            original-from
            original-to
            original-subject
            original-text
            notification-from
            notification-to
            notification-subject
            notification-text
            raw-message
```

When I sent all of the required POST params, I indeed saw my bounce handler get the request and log the appropriate information.